# C++ template specialization problem with const char*

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function `void foo(const T&)`. I need specialized implementations for `[T = int]` and `[T = const char*]`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void foo(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}

template<>
void foo(const int& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 42;
    const char *bar = "xyz";
    foo(i);
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

The specialization for `[T = int]` works, the output is:

```
void foo(const T&) [with T = int]
42
void foo(const T&) [with T = const char*]
xyz
```

But, it won't compile if I try to specialize for `[T = const char*]` like so:

```cpp
template<>
void foo(const char*& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
```

> 17:6: error: template-id 'foo<>' for 'void foo(const char*&)' does not match any template declaration

What has me puzzled is that it appears to correctly deduce `[T = const char*]` when no specialization is present, but complains if I try to implement one.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What if you place the template specialization parameters where they belong? ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/r4jrPjoWa))

Comment: FWIW this can be easily solved by turning those specializations into overloads.  Here is a great video that gets into some of the pitfalls of using specialization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU

Comment: In `const char *p`, `p` itself isn't const. If I'm reading this correctly, your template requires a reference to a const thing, not to a non-const thing that points to a const thing.

Comment: Say it with me: "leading const is misleading!"

Answer (score 6):

You need a second const

```
template<>
void foo(const char* const& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
```

The template requires a const reference, but `const char*&` is a reference to a pointer to a const char.

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T& arg)
```

[Even better would be to use overloads instead of function template specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), e.g.

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}

void foo(const int& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}


void foo(const char*& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "`const char*&` is a reference of a *mutable* pointer to a const char."

Answer (score 0):

In this function template declaration

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
```

you have a constant reference to the type `T`. When the function is called like

```
const char *bar = "xyz";
foo(bar);
```

then the deduced type `T` is `const char *` (the type of a pointer to a string literal).

You may imagine it the following way

```
typedef const char *T;
```

So the constant reference to the type `T` will look like

```
const char * const &
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void foo(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<T, const char *> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( arg ),  const T&> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( arg ),  const char * const &> << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *bar = "xyz";
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
void foo(const T &) [T = const char *]
xyz
true
true
true
```

Compare this program with the program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

typedef const char *T;

void foo(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<T, const char *> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( arg ),  const T&> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_same_v<decltype( arg ),  const char * const &> << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *bar = "xyz";
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above except the first record

```
void foo(const T &)
xyz
true
true
true
```